# Bitmap Scaling On Individual Windows in HiDPI Display on Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, high-dpi, wayland

Both Windows 8.1 or newer and macOS will resize an individual window on bitmap basis (resulting in blurry windows but proportionally correct) of an application if that application's window doesn't declare that they supports DPI scaling mode or retina display mode. Is it possible to do the same on Linux (be it in X11 environment or Wayland)?

Please note that using separate X11 display with VNC is not an option, since it incurs some significant lag and disables DRI and OpenGL. And lowering the entire desktop resolution is also not an option, since very high resolution is the reason I bought a high DPI display.

Here is the example
[macOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOVqH.jpg). Notice that the XQuartz window (the one that is displaying XTerm) doesn't support HiDPI scaling, so that macOS render that window in original resolution and scales that window up using bitmap method, resulting in blurry and pixelated window. The other windows (XQuartz update and macOS built-in terminal) supports HiDPI, so macOS resizes them up using proper retina display method instead of bitmap.

Here is another [screenshot from Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VANR3.png). Notice that the Mikrotik's Winbox doesn't support HiDPI display scaling, so that Windows 10 renders the Window at 96 dpi and scales that window up using bitmap method, resulting in blurry and pixelated window.